# What will be reason behind this error?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am fresher in iphone programming.Whenever i create a new project in x-code it's giving this error.Please anybody, help me to solve this problem.I am attaching snapshot below:-
[image]

It'll be a great help. Thank you

Comment: Do you have these files in your Class folder ?

Comment: You've been asking questions about iPhone programming on SO since December last year - how can you still be a "fresher" ?

Comment: it's not mine account,This account belongs to previous developer.

Comment: Then please create your own account.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add those missing headers to your project.

Comment: Paul please make it clear ,which missing headers you are talking about?

Comment: Raman : testProjectAppDelegate.h and testProjectViewController.h

Comment: if i am not wrong ,when we create a new project and choose View based templete then X-Code automatically adds 4 file appDelegate.h ,appDelegate.m ,ViewController.h,ViewController.m ok, so i think we do not need to add these file manually,Doesn't it?

Comment: @RAMAN: look at the actual errors messages - as Akshay says, you have headers named testProjectAppDelegate.h and testProjectViewController.h which you are trying to use but which you have either not added to your project or which have been moved or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

check out your .h file.

Might be you had deleted @end by mistake or somewhere ‘;’ is missing after statement declarations.